# Livewire actions get 302 response

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a laravel project deployed on a domain subfolder

- https://example.com => another project
- https://example.com/dashboard => my laravel project

I have set my livewire config `asset_url` to `config('app.url')`, which my `.env`'s APP_URL is `https://example.com/dashboard`
It is a simple project that has an auth middleware which protect https://example.com/dashboard and redirect it to https://example.com/dashboard/login. And when I try to fill the input (it has `wire:model` attribute), I get an error at my JS console

`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at index.js:58`

When I check the Network tab, there were some process:

- https://example.com/dashboard/livewire/message/login (post) => 302 (i think it is not expected)
- https://example.com/dashboard/login (get) => 200 (i think it makes the error above)

It works fine if I deploy it to https://example.com, but at https://example.com/dashboard it keeps getting this issue

Could you guys help me?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the livewire.php config folder, maybe you have to change the path for the Livewire assets

Comment: I've change livewire's config `asset_url` to config('app.url')